# MYSQL Datetime getting a date extract one month back

Tags: mysql

having a current date as `2011/12/05` .. , how to get a date extract one month back ? `2011/11/05` ? in MYsql?

Comment: Your question title says "PHP".  But your question body says "MySQL".  Which is it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by adding condition to the WHERE:

```
created_at <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 month)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select date_sub('2011-12-05',interval 1 month);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_SUB(20111205, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
+--------------------------------------+
| DATE_SUB(20111205, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 2011-11-05 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.88 sec)
```

FOR MORE INFO: [Date-Arithmetic-With-MySQL](http://www.weberdev.com/ViewArticle/Date-Arithmetic-With-MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

You also can use

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE createdDate >= (now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

if you're looking for everything created in the last month.